# Почему объекты в findAll(pageable) меняются местами после обновления значения поля, по которому нет сортировки?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

Вот мой репозиторий для `Order`, у которого есть enum `Status`.

```
    @Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {
    Page<Order> findOrdersByStatus(Status status, Pageable pageable);

    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE Order o SET o.status = :status WHERE o.id = :id")
    void updateStatus(@Param(value = "status") Status status, @Param(value = "id") long id);

        @Query("SELECT o.status FROM Order o WHERE o.id=:id")
    Status getStatusById (@Param(value = "id")  long id);
}
```

Каждый раз, когда пользователь нажимает на кнопку `Next Status`, происходит эта логика в контроллере ( для краткости никакого лишнего кода ). Просто устанавливаем следующий enum для этого объекта ( если enum не последний в values() ).

```
 if (action.equals(STATUS_ACTION_DECLINE)) orderService.updateStatus(Status.DECLINED, orderId);
else {
    Status status = orderService.getOrderStatus(orderId);

    if (!status.equals(Status.DECLINED) && !status.equals(Status.COMPLETED))
        orderService.updateStatus(Status.values()[status.ordinal() + 1], orderId);
}
```

Методы, которые тут вызываются, просто делегируют выполнение репозиторию

```
    public Status getOrderStatus(long id) {
    return orderRepository.getStatusById(id);
}
  @Transactional
public void updateStatus(Status status, Long orderId) {
    orderRepository.updateStatus(status, orderId);
}
```

А так мы получаем список `Order` для отображения на странице

```
public Page<Order> findPaginated(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortField, String sortDirection) {

Sort sort = sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortField).ascending() :
        Sort.by(sortField).descending();

Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort);
    System.out.println("PAGEABLE " + pageable);
    return this.orderRepository.findAll(pageable);
```

}

Кажется, все работает хорошо, сколько бы я раз не обновлял страницу - всегда один список
Мы сортируем по этому `Pageable`

```
PAGEABLE Page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: creationDate: ASC]
```

И получаем вот это

```
    Order(id=1, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=2, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=3, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.251971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=4, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=6, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
```

Проблемы начинаются при попытке обновить статус некоторых заказов, вот я у нескольких заказов обновил его через нажатие кнопки.Теперь получаю список заново. `Pageable` не изменился

```
PAGEABLE Page request [number: 0, size 5, sort: creationDate: ASC]
```

Но в списке почему-то id 1 и 2 поменялись местами, почему?

```
  Order(id=2, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=1, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, updateDate=2022-02-03T14:46:04.702056, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=3, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.251971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 1)
Order(id=4, status=PENDING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:02:00.252971, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
Order(id=6, status=COOKING, creationDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, updateDate=2022-02-03T16:06:21.555237, totalPrice=150.00, address=Address 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У этих объектов одинаковый `creationDate`, так что при выбранной сортировке по полю `creationDate` их порядок не гарантирован, а значит может меняться от запроса к запросу.

Чтоб сделать запрос стабильным добавьте вторым полем в порядок сортировки неизменяемое уникальное поле, например, id:

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(
    sortDirection.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? 
        Sort.by(sortField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortField).descending(),
    Sort.by("id").ascending())
```